# ld: framework not found Flutter after migrating project

Tags: xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I get this error message when trying to build flutter app in Xcode:

```
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When reading posts where a similar error has occurred the suggested fix is adding the `Flutter.framework` file to the project, however the steps outlined in this guide involve removing this file:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

When I add the `App.framework` and `Flutter.framework` files back into my app and try and `flutter build ios` in VS Code i get an error telling me to migrate my project with a link to the guide above. So it seems like neither solution works.

This is the output of `flutter doctor --v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/gregorysheen/Dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (10 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gregorysheen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```